Follow Path Constraint not working
I am trying to make a the default cube follow a simple path. But no matter how many times I reset the position of the cube to the origin, the cube just follows it's own path in a straight line (a dotted blue line). I'm only adjusting the influence value. It does not follow the path at all. Can anyone please help me with this? How do I use the follow path constraint properly?
All I've done is create a cube, create a path, edited it so that it looks like a curve and then added the path constraint on the cube, nothing else.




Hello select the cube and press Alt G to make it begin at the beginning of the curve, also make sure that the good axis is selected in the constraint, if it still doesnt work please share the file

Have you clicked 'Animate Path' and then run the timeline?

I've tried Alt G and changing the axis, but it doesn't seem to work, here's the file
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yn5Nr_MY-YB2PsaR5Ce5dWf90xwS1jsi/view?usp=sharing @moonboots

Yes, that seems to work. But, there are no keyframes and I want to be able to control the influence factor for animation. @JohnEason

Don't click on Animate Path otherwise it assigns a Generator modifier to the curve and make the objet move automatically, to cancel that, select the curve, go into the Data panel > Path Animation > right click on Evaluation Time and Clear Keyframes (or remove the Generator modifier of the curve in the Graph Editor). Now you can keyframe the Evaluation Time the way you want.

Thanks a lot @moonboots this worked perfectly. I will use this technique for time being. But it still hasn't solved my problem using "follow path" constraint. I want to be able to use the "influence" factor to animate the object. Any idea how to get that working?

What do you want to do exactly with the influence?

I'm animating a car following a path on a racetrack. I feel I have better control over the object while using the influence factor, but unable to get it to work.

I'm not sure how the Influence value could be better than either the Evaluation Time of the curve or the Offset of the constraint but I may miss something
